# How to get backtracking and IO using ListT?

Tags: haskell, io, generic-list, backtracking, monad-transformers

I don't know really how exactly should the List transformer `ListT` be used. For example how should this simple task be done:

```
backtrack :: ListT IO ()
backtrack = do
    x <- lift getLine
    a <- x
    lift $ print a
```

And what should be the type of the function ?

This is not a task I'm trying to accomplish (I know how to solve this issue using many other methods), I just want to know how to use `ListT` to accomplish such tasks.

Comment: What task are you trying to accomplish? You don't actually say.

Comment: I just want to understand how to use ListT to get the features of the List Monad with IO.
What I actually meant by "This is not a task I'm trying to accomplish" is that I don't want solutions for the problem which do not use `ListT`, because I already know how to accomplish this using `mapM` for example.

Comment: `a <- x` doesn't make much sense since `x` is of the "monad type", eg, the normal `a` in `m a`. Likely you want `x <- liftGetline; lift $ print a`?

Comment: `ListT` from the standard library does not actually do backtracking.  `ListT m` is also not a monad in general when in `m` is.  There is a good implementation of `ListT`, but I can't seem to find it right now :-(

Comment: @monadic Thanks for you contribution but I didn't really understand you question. @luqui are you talking about LogicT ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to do?

```
import Control.Monad.List

backtrack :: ListT IO ()
backtrack = do
    x <- ListT getLine
    lift $ print x
```

Example run in GHCi:

```
*Main> runListT backtrack
foo
'f'
'o'
'o'
[(), (), ()]
```

Comment: Yes this is similar to what I want. But why did you use the `ListT` constructor in `x <- ListT getLine` should'nt `lift` be used for actions in the inner monad ?

Comment: You could also write it as `do x <- lift getLine; a <- ListT (return x); lift $ print a`. Perhaps that's easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at [ListT done right](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ListT_done_right) and the backtracking [LogicT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict) packages.  In particular [interleave](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/logict/0.4.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Logic-Class.html#v%3ainterleave) in logict handles infinities better.